# How to set x-model and name of Input field inside x-for in alpine js?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am getting an issue saving the data with alpine js.
I have a form inside a for loop. but, i am unable to set the index for x-model and name of form inputs.

**HTML:**

```html
<template x-for="(price, index) in prices">
    <tr data-id="price.id">
        <td class="text-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" x-bind:name="record.items[${index}].batch" x-model="record.items[${index}].batch">
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

**Javscript**

```
record: {
    items: [],
}
```

I got this error.
`Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined`.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/codedge/pen/abBLELM) illustrating how you can use the `index` inside an `x-for` loop and reference items.

The usage of `${index}` in your code seems wrong to me. You should be able to use it just like `[index]`:

```html
<div x-data="{ prices: myPrices, items: record.items }">
      <template x-for="(price, index) in prices">
        <div>
            <span x-text="price.id"></span>
            <input type="text" x-bind:name="items[index]" x-bind:placeholder="items[index]">
        </div>
      </template>
</div>
```

Please see the full CodePen for all details.